# How to refer to weekdays

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

I am curious what is the most correct way to communicate what you do during the week. I have seen in a dictionary that it is possible to use:

> *Am Montag* ...

And there is the variant:

> *Montags* ...

Are there any distinctions between these two?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use for example:

> *Montags höre ich Musik.*

This implies that you normally hear music every monday.

Otherwise if you use for example:

> *Am Montag höre ich Musik.*

You hear music this monday.

The distinction between these two options is that *'Wochentag + s'* implies that you normally always do an specific action on this day.

Comment: So like "mondays" and "on monday" in English :)

Comment: Vielen dank Em1 and Cryck.

Comment: The weekdays take "Der" as an article and you can see that **Am Montag** is actually, **An dem Montag**. From the usage of article, you can understand that a certain monday is meant, not any monday.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Vielen dank.

Comment: And if you have present after the _Am Montag_, it implies the nearest future Monday, so basically _next Monday_. If however you say _Am Montag hörte ich Musik_ that's past, so it implies the previous Monday, unless you were specifically talking about e.g. three weeks ago.

Comment: @simbabque: Thanks a lot. I highly appreciate your comment. There are many small things that you all contribute with that do not exist in the dictionaries or other Resources but are extremely important for novices like me.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass *montags* eher als *meistens, an Montagen*, nicht an allen. *Samstags schaue ich Sportschau* kann ich durchaus mit dem Vorbehalt *während der Bundesligasaison und wenn nichts wichtiges dazwischenkommt* sagen. Meist wird es so benutzt und so verstanden. Auch weil es die meisten Montage in der Geschichte gar kein Fernsehen gab.

Comment: Ich hab es dahingehend noch einmal überarbeitet und 'normally' hinzugefügt, da es sonst einen falschen Eindruck einer hundertprozentigen Stetigkeit abgeben könnte.

Answer (score 5):

The easier part is *montags*. We use it for activities that we do or that happen regularly or at least frequently on Mondays.

> Montags bin ich immer so müde.
>   Donnerstags gehe ich zum Gesangsunterricht.
>   Sonntags bleibe ich gerne bis Mittag im Bett.
>   Bis 2015 erschien *Der Spiegel* immer montags.

*Am Montag* is more difficult. You need to take care of the context. Often it means a specific day:

> Wollen wir nächste Woche ins Kino gehen?
>   Keine Zeit - am Montag ist Elternabend in der Schule, am Dienstag muss ich meine Steuerklärung machen, am Mittwoch packen wir die Koffer, und am Donnerstag fahren wir übers Wochenende zu meinen Schwiegereltern.

But it can also be used as a synonym to *montags*. Look e.g. at [this message](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/der-spiegel-erscheint-jetzt-am-samstag-a-1012015.html) from *Der Spiegel*. In the text body they write

> Der SPIEGEL erscheint nun immer samstags.

But the breadcrumb navigation in the header reads

> Der SPIEGEL erscheint jetzt am Samstag.

Or if someone talks about her childhood you might hear her saying

> Am Sonntag gingen wir immer in die Kirche zum Gottesdienst.

and it means that they went to church (almost) every Sunday.

Comment: Kommt das Sams eigentlich jeden Samstag oder nur an einem bestimmten?

Comment: @CarstenS Da musst Du jemand anders fragen. In meiner Kindheit war samstags immer Sonnabend.

Comment: Haha, ja, das steht hier an den Bushaltestellen. Dann lebst Du jetzt wohl im Exil.